# Driver (filter) for avoiding loss of mouse focus / capture with touch screen operation

Tags: windows, kernel, driver, touch-event, hid

Presently we are exploring a particular case for one of our product, where there will be two operators one as controller or administrator other as operator or user.
Administrator will be sitting on main screen with same PC as operator, operator will have a small touch screen with very limited operation. Both will work together to complete a single operation using a single PC, to operate an external hardware.
(note that both screen are in extended mode)

But when operator touches on touch screen unfortunately mouse pointer shifts to touch screen, can they operate real time co-operatively.
We planning to write a filter driver and hold mouse pointer on the same location and visible for administrator screen, without wobble and both users operate unrestricted.

Are we following right direction, is this operation can be done collaboratively between these two users? Requesting if any other solution or driver related suggestions.

If someone has already explored this requirement already, kindly provide some links and their resolve for it.

Thanking in advance

We have tried filtering with raw input and captured and restored mouse location, but mouse pointer keeps wobbling, which we are intended to remove.

We are planning to write a kernel mode filter driver for this purpose, and require to know if we are in right direction.